# How to find my VPN client IP in windows

Tags: windows, command-line, ip-address

When I run `ipconfig` and I get the following:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\grmsrh14>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration

Ethernet adapter Wireless Network Connection:

        Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 112.25.2.222
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.254.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 112.25.2.1
        DHCP Class ID . . . . . . . . . . : rise

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

        Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected

PPP adapter my_lab:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.2.251.41
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

Is there a command that prints only the my_lab(VPN) IP address, ie **10.2.251.41**?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`netsh`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/netsh.mspx?mfr=true) command:

For Vista/7:

```
netsh interface ipv4 show addresses "PPP adapter my_lab"
```

And one of these for XP:

```
netsh interface ip show config "PPP adapter my_lab"
```

Where *PPP adapter my_lab* can be replaced by the name of any one of your adapters.

Comment: On XP, wouldn't it be `netsh interface ip show address "PPP adapter my_lab"`?

Comment: Yes, updated accordingly

Comment: These commands give good information, but not "only the my_lab(VPN) IP address, ie 10.2.251.41"

Comment: And simply `netsh interface ip show config` (with no name) will give all configs.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the ip range of the my_lab VPN?

If you do, a batch file like this will do the trick:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('IPCONFIG ^|FIND "IP" ^|FIND "10.2"') do set _IP=%%a
set IP=%_IP:~1%
echo %IP%
```

But, as it was suggested by heavyd, if you know only the name of the PPP adapter it's better to use the netsh command.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=1-6 delims=:. " %%a in ('netsh int ip show address "my_lab" ^|find "IP Address"') do set IP=%%c.%%d.%%e.%%f
echo %IP%
```

-**Updated**

Comment: thanks for your reply. Unfortunatelly, no. I don't know the range.

Comment: +1 for the first script. My VPN does not even show up in the listing when I run 'netsh int ip show address', so the second script does not work for me (using Windows XP). I think I know the range though so this solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run: `ipconfig /all`
will show the VPN addresses.