# List VPN connections and properties in command prompt

Tags: command-line, windows-8.1, vpn

Is there a command, in `cmd` or `PowerShell` for Windows VPN like there is for wifi, to list and edit profiles?

Like this is for wifi. (just an example)

> netsh wlan show profiles

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  VPN connections look like adapters.  Take a look at this question: [How to find my VPN client IP in windows](https://superuser.com/questions/113271/how-to-find-my-vpn-client-ip-in-windows)